# find similar sub-sequence in a very large sequence

Tags: c++, sql, database, algorithm

Imaging that sequence is Pi

141592653589793238462643383279502884197....

the Pi is stored in a text file.

I want to locate a similar sub-sequence in the Pi with for example 80% similarity.

for example I want to locate **33384** in Pi, so

14159265358979 **32384** 62643383279502884197....

the number of digits is about millions.

I need an efficient algorithm to search for these similarity.

Should I use database instead file?

any Idea appreciated.

**EDIT**:

I found some algorithm, I need to check it and I'll let you know the result.

BTW the algorithm is [Knuth–Morris–Pratt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm)

Comment: preffered will be performing this in database, if its being stored in db

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee: Can you please elaborate on your comment. Why do you think database is the preferred place for the requirement

Comment: because instead of writing an algo then check for its performance, one shou use db indexing I guess

Comment: and where would your store such a sequence? as a BLOB column, or each digit separately in each row?

Comment: db or file is not the problem, how I should search for the sub-sequence with X% similarity?

Comment: how long is the sub-sequence? and is this contiguous sub-sequence, or just any sub-sequence?

Comment: sub-sequence is variable. Its somehow is user input.

Comment: @dare sub-sequence means 12345 so 135 can be a subsequence of 12345, while contiguous sub-sequence is 123 or 345. You should define how to calculate the similarity. and if the length of user input is 1000, so a O(n*m) with n is length of Pi and m is length of user input is acceptable

Comment: @PhamTrung so 2234 is a sub-sequence of 12345 with 75% similarity

Comment: @dare, can you read about [sub-sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence) and we need an exact formula.

Comment: I would use C++, more specifically C. Scan through all characters  and do strchr() of each of the searching elements of the searched string. I do not have time to write a small program, but seems to be very easy. If it is not answered by tomorrow, will give you one

Comment: @PhamTrung there is no specific formula. And I think I clear the meaning of sequence and sub-seq by example and I couldn't find more properiate words than those.

Comment: Btw, how big is the sub-sequence? Is it also millions of digits? Or it is relatively small, like in your example

Comment: It's user input @cha. I don't want to limit it.

Answer (score 2):

You can go through the pi sequence extracting M chars (M - length of the search) subsequence. Then compare the subsequence with the search string.

Then just XOR search and the subsequence. After XOR count not 0 bytes. The count is number of differences. Comparing the differences count with search string length gives you percent of difference.

if the difference is suitable you get the similar substring.

UPDATE:

You will get N-M times the subsequeces and comparing complexisy is O(M). N is the pi string length and M is substring length

Comment: in what environment you say i have to do this?

Comment: does not matter. Supppose the pi sequence is file then you just read N bytes from the file. It could be an array if you have enough memory.

Comment: the XOR complexity is O(M).
and I have to do XOR through the whole sequence 
so I think the complexity will be O(MN)
am i right?

Comment: For the worst case the complexity O(NM) right. You can compare byte by byte till the number of differences is less than max allowed.

Comment: The XOR works well for bitwise sequence comparisons. OP needs a byte-wise comparison algorithm - so treating each character as a byte value and threshold based subtraction is probably a good starting point. The general logic for count and percentage confidence holds though.

Comment: I don't see the gain of XOR.

Comment: @Jarod42 agree. Just == is enough

Answer (score 1):

I think a [C++ program](http://ideone.com/GF9K98) as simple as this will do. It is my own algorithm the way I see it done. I have attempted to optimise it a bit, so that the inner `for` does not loop when it is confirmed that there are already so many unmatched elements that the test for the reset of the searching string is not necessary:

```
int main()
{
   char *input = "141592653589793238462643383279502884197";
   char *test  = "33384";
   double pc   = .8;

   int len  = strlen(test);
   int good = len * pc;

   for(int pos = 0; pos < strlen(input)-len; ++pos)
   {
       int matches = 0;
       for(int pos1 = 0; pos1 < len; ++pos1)
       {
           if(test[pos1] == input[pos + pos1]) matches++;

           // below is a small optimisation attempt. It should significantly improve the performance
           if(len - pos1 < good - matches)
                break; // exiting earlier. no reason to stay in the loop
       }

       if(matches >= good)
       {
            cout << pos << " " << input + pos << endl;
       }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Please test it with your real data and advise how fast it is.

Comment: your program's complexity is not linear, it's O(NM). I'm working on a linear complexity algorithm. I'll let you know about my progress.

Comment: While I agree that the complexity is not linear, it is not O(NM) either. It depends on the similarity chosen. The closer it is to 1 the more linear the complexity is.

Answer (score 0):

I will take the liberty of offering my own definition of 80% similarity: in a given sequence, when a position in the sequence is selected at random, there is an 80% chance that the digit at that position in the sequence will match the digit in the same position of the target sequence.

Given that definition and its rather fuzzy nature, I propose a relatively efficient heuristic algorithm which will usually return correct results for reasonably long sub-sequences:

1. Loop through each digit in pi (up to a given length). For each one, sample several (depending on length of the sub-sequence) digits at random offsets from the current position (ranging from 0 to the length of the sub-sequence-1). If you cannot conclude with reasonable statistical significance that the region has less than 80% match, mark this position to return to later.
2. Re-test each marked region with a larger sample size until the sample size is approaching the length of the sub-sequence.
3. Verify the remaining regions to see which ones truly have at least 80% match.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of code I created in C# with passing pi as a string.  You can probably convert this to a stream or something depending on how you are getting pi.  It will return a list of partially matched strings.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        string pi = "141592653589793238462643383279502884197";
        string searchStr = "33384";
        double matchPercentage = 0.8;
        var matchedStrings = GetMatchedStrings(searchStr, matchPercentage, pi);
        Assert.AreEqual(1, matchedStrings.Count);

        searchStr = "141";
        matchPercentage = 0.6666;
        matchedStrings = GetMatchedStrings(searchStr, matchPercentage, pi);
        Assert.AreEqual(2, matchedStrings.Count);
    }

    private static List<string> GetMatchedStrings(string searchStr, double matchPercentage, string pi)
    {
        int currentPosition = 0;
        int searchLength = searchStr.Length;
        int minMatchCount = Convert.ToInt32(searchLength*matchPercentage);
        List<string> matchedStrings = new List<string>();

        while (currentPosition + searchLength <= pi.Length)
        {
            int matchedCount = 0;
            int checkedCount = 0;
            while (searchLength - checkedCount + matchedCount >= minMatchCount)
            {
                if (searchStr[checkedCount] == pi[currentPosition + checkedCount])
                    matchedCount++;
                if (matchedCount >= minMatchCount)
                {
                    matchedStrings.Add(pi.Substring(currentPosition, searchLength));
                    break;
                }
                checkedCount ++;
            }
            currentPosition ++;
        }
        return matchedStrings;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
declare @string varchar(500) = '141592653589793238462643383279502884197'

DECLARE @start int

set @start = patindex('%32384%', @string)

print @start

--get start position
```

Note: if value then zero not found, refer [PatIndex](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx)

Comment: how will this search with 80% accuracy?

Comment: @cha, I don't know what you mean by 80% accuracy. I tested , it works like charm.

Comment: The problem is search for 33384 and the result is 32384. It is not searching for 32384

Comment: @dare when I search for 33384, return 0, means not found in string.

Comment: so your code is wrong as @PhamTrung said. Thanks for your interest

Comment: sorry guys, I misunderstood the question.

Comment: No problem :), you can try again any times :D